# How would I go about coding a UIView fade-in animation for bringSubviewToFront

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, xcode10

I am attempting to add a UIView Animation/fade-in effect to my function: 
`self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.webView)`

I've tried implementing it programmatically, but the UIView doesn't animate; instead, it just shows it immediately without the fade-in effect:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.webView)
        }, completion: nil)
```

How would I go about implementing an animation for the `bringSubview(_: )` and `sendSubview(_ : )` functions? I've tried looking everywhere, but no one seems to have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `UIView.animate` like that. It only works on certain properties. In this case, you need to animate the `alpha` property.

Before you start animating, set the view's `alpha` to 0 then bring it to front:

```
self.webView.alpha = 0
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.webView)
// After that you animate the alpha:
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    self.webView.alpha = 1
}, completion: nil)
```